# Can we have cryptocurrency transaction without knowing Privatekey

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency, mining

From [open-node-mining-portal](https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal)

[open-node-mining-portal](https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal) is program that will use your computer as your own mining pool.

Congfig.json file only know **address** where reward is sent from cryptocurrency

But how can [open-node-mining-portal](https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal) send this reward to workers(or miners) if you dont know the privatekey of that **address**

For example I found 1 block of bitcoin and I get reward(maybe 6.25btc) to “myTempAddress” and now [open-node-mining-portal](https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal) try to send 1btc to “myRealAddress” and maybe 0.1btc to [“workerAddress1”,“workerAddress2”,...,“workerAddressN”] but [open-node-mining-portal](https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal) dont know the privatekey of “myTempAddress”.

So the question is how [open-node-mining-portal](https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal) have transaction without privatekey?

Comment: That is impossible.

Comment: In the config file you must provide an address that you have private key